# Is there any other way to get the special halloween items for Scream Fortress 2014?

Tags: team-fortress-2

This year for Scream Fortress 2014, each player recieved a special cauldron that dispenses 3 special items for the update.  Is there any method, besides, natural item dropping and trades, to get more Halloween items?

Comment: Your secondary question would pretty much require a Valve developer to answer it.

Comment: @Powerlord Good point. Pulling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other method I know of is to get one of the new crates.  However, Valve did something different with crates this year:  Instead of the crates being free and the keys costing money, instead the Unlocked Creepy Crates cost money and don't require a key.

There are 9 Unlocked Creepy Crates, one per class.

**Tradeability**

- Items from the free cauldron can **not** be traded, but they can be giftwrapped.
- Items from the Unlocked Creepy Crates **can** be traded.

On a side note, Halloween items aren't part of the normal drop system, so you can't get one as a regular hat drop.

Comment: @Zibbobz Well, the Arqade chat room tells you when new questions are asked and I've been participating heavily in the TF2 event as a server owner, player, and plugin developer.  I'm wearing my player hat here, the other question (which you left a comment on) I'm wearing my server owner and plugin developer hats.